# How to read a gzip jsonl from a byte offset to debug a BigQuery error?

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery, gzip

I am exporting json newline files into BigQuery and the BigQuery errors give me a byte offset of the original gziped jsonl file such as

```
JSON parsing error in row starting at position 727720: Repeated field must be imported as a JSON array. Field: named_entities.alt_form."
```

I have tried using the Python package [indexed gzip](https://github.com/pauldmccarthy/indexed_gzip) to read from the offset but indexed gzip mangles the lines sadly. I have also tried using the builtin python gzip package to try and get the relevant line unsuccessfully:

```
import gzip
import ujson as json

f = open('myfile.json.gz', 'rb')
g = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
fasz = g.read()
byte_offset_to_line = {}
for line in g:
    byte_offset = f.tell()
    byte_offset_to_line[byte_offset] = line


target = 727720
ls = sorted([(abs(target-k),k) for k in byte_offset_to_line.keys() if k < target])

line_of_interest = byte_offset_to_line[ls[0]]
text = str(line_of_interest)

malformed_json = json.loads(text[2:-3])
```

With the above snippet I can get the nearest line's byte offset. But then when I tried just uploading that line to a test table in BQ it works sadly so I think I am not getting the correct line.

I was wondering if there's a better approach to solve this problem? I am not sure why my above snippet doesn't work to be honest.

Comment: What happens if for debugging purposes you gunzip the file and work with those numbers from then on?

Comment: Have you tried to supply your code with [seek()](https://code-maven.com/python-seek) method for offset pointer?